# Vertical column highlighting using React

Tags: reactjs, onhover

I have the following HTML-

```
<div class="hmap">
    <div class="Row" id="row1">
        <div class="Squares"></div>
        <div class="Squares"></div>
        <div class="Squares"></div>
        <div class="Squares"></div>
        <div class="Squares"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row" id="row2">
        <div class="Squares"></div>
        <div class="Squares"></div>
        <div class="Squares"></div>
        <div class="Squares"></div>
        <div class="Squares"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row" id="row3">
        <div class="Squares"></div>
        <div class="Squares"></div>
        <div class="Squares"></div>
        <div class="Squares"></div>
        <div class="Squares"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On hover, I am trying to highlight the squares verticaly, in each row using React. I tried using the onmouseEnter & onmouseLeave in React. I was able to add a class, but it was added to all the 'squares'.
However was not able to achieve the desired result. 
This can be easily achieved in tables. However, am not in favor of using tables. Any pointers  would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the problem comes from the structure of your table. You have to find a way to identify each column, maybe you could try this:

```
<div class="Row" id="row1">
    <div id="column1" class="Squares"></div>
    <div id="column2" class="Squares"></div>
    <div id="column3" class="Squares"></div>
    <div id="column4" class="Squares"></div>
    <div id="column5" class="Squares"></div>
</div>
```

Then you add a logic, if on column1, do something to all column1